# C# HTTP Web Request CookieContainer to webBrowser.Document.Cookie

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, browser, cookiecontainer

```
string cookie_string = "";
requestss9.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

WebRespx1ss9.Cookies = requestss9.CookieContainer.GetCookies(requestss9.RequestUri);

foreach (Cookie cook in WebRespx1ss9.Cookies)
{
    cookie_string += cook.ToString() + ";";
}

webBrowser1.Document.Cookie = cookie_string;
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate(Action, true);

requestss9 = HTTP Web Request;
WebRespx1ss9 = HTTP Web Response;
```

*Problem is `webBrowser1.Document.Cookie = cookie_string;` returns with object reference not set to an instance of an object.
How do I set that to a reference to the object?  I tried `webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();` But, it did not work.

Comment: I already have the webrowser loaded to a web page before I try and modify the cookies.

Comment: it's definitely talking about either the webBrowser1 or webBrowser1.Document, make sure webBrowser1 is initialized and has browsed to a page, try running through the debugger to see if one of them is null